# Paste string into preceding column if no match is found

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe that roughly looks like this:

```
Col1      Col2     Col3
listerine DB0076 
listerine DB0076
nicotine  Acetate  DB0071
```

I want the dataframe to look like this. Essentially asking, if there is no `DB` in the second column, paste it to `Col1` in that row.

```
Col1               Col2
listerine          DB0076 
listerine          DB0076
nicotine Acetate   DB0071
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a `tidyverse` approach.

### Data

```
df <-
  structure(list(Col1 = c("listerine", "listerine", "nicotine"), 
                 Col2 = c("DB0076", "DB0076", "Acetate"),
                 Col3 = c(NA, NA,"DB0071")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

### Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    Col1 = if_else(!str_detect(Col2,"DB"), paste(Col1,Col2),Col1),
    Col2 = if_else(!str_detect(Col2,"DB"), Col3,Col2)
  ) %>% 
  select(-Col3)
```

### Output

```
              Col1   Col2
1        listerine DB0076
2        listerine DB0076
3 nicotine Acetate DB0071
```